# How to draw a Tetrahedron mesh by matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tetrahedra

I want to plot a tetrahedron mesh by `matplotlib`, and the following are a simple tetrahedron mesh:

```
xyz = np.array([
    [-1,-1,-1],
    [ 1,-1,-1], 
    [ 1, 1,-1],
    [-1, 1,-1],
    [-1,-1, 1],
    [ 1,-1, 1], 
    [ 1, 1, 1],
    [-1, 1, 1]], dtype=np.float) 

tets = np.array([
    [0,1,2,6],
    [0,5,1,6],
    [0,4,5,6],
    [0,7,4,6],
    [0,3,7,6],
    [0,2,3,6]], dtype=np.int)
```

Of course, in practical applications, the number of tetrahedrons in a mesh can be large. I can't find any useful help information in google. So what is the better way to plot a tetrahedron mesh by `matplotlib`?

Furthermore, I can get all the triangle faces of the mesh.

```
tri = np.array([
    [0, 2, 1],
    [0, 1, 5],
    [0, 6, 1],
    [0, 3, 2],
    [0, 2, 6],
    [0, 6, 3],
    [0, 7, 3],
    [0, 5, 4],
    [0, 6, 4],
    [0, 4, 7],
    [0, 6, 5],
    [0, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 6],
    [5, 1, 6],
    [2, 3, 6],
    [3, 7, 6],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 4, 6]], dtype=np.int)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

matplotlib is perhaps the wrong tool for the task. 3D plotting is hard, and there is, e.g., [ParaView](https://www.paraview.org) to try out. You can use [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (a project of mine) to write your mesh to an appropriate data type:

```
import meshio
meshio.write('out.vtu', xyz, {'tetra': tets})
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good work. Can `meshio` read and write obj mesh file?

Comment: Would be nice if `meshio` could make use of matplotlib to draw a mesh while debugging

Answer (score 5):

One can use [`mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.html):

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as a3
axes = a3.Axes3D(pl.figure())
vts = xyz[tri, :]
tri = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection(vts)
tri.set_alpha(0.2)
tri.set_color('grey')
axes.add_collection3d(tri)
axes.plot(point[:,0], point[:,1], point[:,2], 'ko')
axes.set_axis_off()
axes.set_aspect('equal')
pl.show()
```