# How to save a triangular mesh in python

Tags: python, mesh, mplot3d

I have a set of vertices and triangular faces, which together form a triangular mesh:

```
import numpy as np

verts = [[0.1, 1.,  1. ]  [1.,  1.,  0.1]  [1.,  0.1, 1. ]  [1.,  1.,  1.9]  [1.,  1.9, 1. ]
 [1.9, 1.,  1. ] ]
faces = [[ 2,  1,  0]  [ 0,  3,  2]  [ 1,  4,  0]  [ 0,  4,  3]  [ 5,  1,  2]  [ 3,  5,  2]
 [ 5,  4,  1]  [ 4,  5,  3]]
```

The only way I know to create from these a triangular mesh is using `Poly3Dcollection`

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

myMesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces])
```

Next, I want to use the [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh) module to create a volume mesh.  It should take in a surface mesh and output a volume mesh, like is shown [here](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh#volume-meshes-from-surface-meshes).

According to the tutorial, I should be able to create a volume mesh using:

```
import pygalmesh

mesh = pygalmesh.generate_volume_mesh_from_surface_mesh(
    "elephant.vtu",
    facet_angle=25.0,
    facet_size=0.15,
    facet_distance=0.008,
    cell_radius_edge_ratio=3.0,
    verbose=False
)
```

However, when I run:

```
mesh = pygalmesh.generate_volume_mesh_from_surface_mesh(myMesh)
```

I am returned:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Poly3DCollection
```

I think this is because I am either creating my mesh incorrectly, or that I am meant to save it in some form before using `pygalmesh.generate_volume_mesh_from_surface_mesh`. I'm not sure. I've raised the issue in the modules [github](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh/issues/93), but haven't received good feedback yet.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354263/12063126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Paddy Harrison's advice, I used `meshio`'s `write` function. Specifically, with my dataset, it is done like so:

```
import meshio 

points = np.array(verts)
cells = [("triangle", np.array(faces)]
meshio.write_points_cells('out.vtu',points,cells)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [OpenSTL](https://github.com/Innoptech/OpenSTL), which is the fastest and most intuitive python library for STL file and vertices manipulation. Install with `pip install openstl`.

```py
import openstl
import numpy as np

# Define an array of triangles
# Following the STL standard, each triangle is defined with : normal, v0, v1, v2
quad = np.array([
    [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]],
    [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]],
])

# Serialize the triangles to a file
success = openstl.write("quad.stl", quad, openstl.format.binary) # Or openstl.format.ascii (slower but human readable)
```